# How can I convert an Array to Json (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, jackson

I want to convert an Array into a Json Object like

```
String[] array = {"value1", "value2"};
```

into

```
{
  "array": ["value1", "value2"]
}
```

I am using Spring (Jackson XML).

I tried:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode jsonNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();

String[] array = {"value1", "value2"};
jsonNode.put("array", Arrays.toString(array));

System.out.print(jsonNode.toString());
```

But the result is

```
{
  "array":"[value1, value2]"
}
```

And not

```
{
  "array":["value1", "value2"]
}
```

what I want to get.

Comment: It shoud work properly if You won't call `Arrays.toString` and instead pass the array itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting `Array` of strings into string and adding it to json object

```
String[] array = {"value1", "value2"};
String arr = Arrays.toString(array)   //converting array into string
```

Just add the array directly to `ObjectNode` using [putArray](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#putArray(java.lang.String))

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = jsonNode.putArray("array");
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(str->arrayNode.add(str));
```

or you can also use `addAll` directly by converting array into `ArrayNode`

```
jsonNode.putArray("array").addAll(objectMapper.valueToTree(array));
```